# Info: 'runZoned' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. This will be removed in v9.0.0. Use Bloc.Bloc.transformer instead

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am getting this issue while trying to run my code on DartPad.

```
'runZoned' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. This will be removed in v9.0.0. Use Bloc.Bloc.transformer instead...
```

What is the correct way to replace it?

code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  BlocOverrides.runZoned(
    () => runApp(const App()),
    blocObserver: AppBlocObserver(),
  );
}

/// Custom [BlocObserver] that observes all bloc and cubit state changes.
class AppBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Change change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    if (bloc is Cubit) print(change);
  }

  @override
  void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {
    super.onTransition(bloc, transition);
    print(transition);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Solution is :

```
void main() {
  Bloc.observer = AppBlocObserver();
  runApp(const App());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The above code, while appearing harmless, can actually lead to many difficult to track *bugs*.
Due to the use of the **runZoned**, the transition to the *BlocOverrides* API led to the discovery of several bugs/limitations in *Flutter*

**https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96939**

To **fix** this, use the following way of creating ***observers*** and ***transformers*** as given by the [Bloc team](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration)

```
void main() {
  Bloc.observer = AppBlocObserver();
  Bloc.transformer = customEventTransformer();

  // ...
}
```

**[You can read more about bloc on their official website.](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/)**

Answer (score 0):

For me this did the trick:

before:

```
BlocOverrides.runZoned( () {
  runApp(
    BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => AppBloc(
        screen: AppScreen.home,
      )..add(const AppStarted(screen: AppScreen.home)),
      child: const App(),
    ),
  );
},
blocObserver: SimpleBlocObserver(),
```

);

after:

```
Bloc.observer = SimpleBlocObserver();
runApp(
  BlocProvider(
    create: (_) => AppBloc(
      screen: AppScreen.home,
    )..add(const AppStarted(screen: AppScreen.home)),
    child: const App(),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this Solution :-

write this code in main app file =>    `Bloc.observer = AppBlocObserver();`

[image]